# Manage Promotion in smart target

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I have created a promotion with when trigger date is 30 jan 2015 - 31 jan 2015 in targeting tab in CME which should not visible today

But its visible on browser .Any help regarding the same highly appreciated

Comment: It's not off by a lot, so is it possible that you have different timezones between your CM/CD/FH machines and you haven't properly configured the offset in the SmartTarget configuration?

Comment: CM/CD/FH are on the same machine

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the details of your Promotion? At least the triggers section would be helpful. Also, what is the time zone offset set to in your configuration?

Comment: Of course, by now it probably is January 30 (depending on where in the world you are) so you maybe you could try bumping the date back a few days to see if the Promotion still shows up.

Comment: Also, where are you seeing the Promotion? You just said it was visible in your browser -- but is that from a query done on your website? The Targeting section always shows all of the Promotions.

Answer (score 5):

For this to work, the trigger needs to be mapped to a value in your ADF.

I wrote a blog post [here](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/plugging-the-context-engine-into-smarttarget) that shows the steps to wire up the Context Engine into SmartTarget, the steps are essentially the same you just need to wire up to the source of where your date is coming from.

In short:

- Your app puts the date into the ADF
- Configure this in your smarttarget_conf.xml
- Configure the value from your conf into the Trigger types

Then it should magically work :)

If you've done these steps, perhaps you could share some of your config files?

Comment: You're right about these steps, of course, but I would expect the symptoms to be that the Promotion *doesn't* show up if this was the cause. Since the Promotion is showing up when it shouldn't, I think we need to look elsewhere for the cause of the problem.

Comment: that's a good point Peter.  @hem perhaps you can share a little more about the implementation?